# UK MSc vs MEng when applying for PhD and Chartered Engineer

Tags: phd, masters, undergraduate, electrical-engineering

I did my **BEng electrical and electronic** undergraduate degree in UK university. It was 3 year degree. So I want clear idea of MSc and MEng and also about Chartered Engineer qualification. Please kindly clear my doubts.

1. **MSc** is postgraduate degree in **UK, USA, Canada** and so on. Is it right?
2. **UK MEng** is undergraduate degree in **USA, Canada** and so on. But **UK MEng** is  postgraduate degree. Is it right?
3. Therefor If I did **MEng** electrical and electronic in **UK**, Is it equal to **BSc in USA, Canada** and so on? Because **MEng** is **undergraduate degree** and **BEng + MEng** is **4 year undergraduate degree**.
4. I can get **Chartered Engineer** qualification in **UK** but I can't get engineering courses membership in other counties because **BEng** is **3 year degree**. If I did **MEng**, can I get **USA engineering courses membership**? Because then I have  **4 year undergraduate degree**.
5. If I did **MEng undergraduate degree**, can I did directly **PhD in USA or Canada**?  or Do I want to do **MSc  postgraduate degree** to do **PhD** in **USA**?

Comment: *MEng is undergraduate degree in USA, Canada* - No. Where did you hear that?

Comment: M.E. is *Master* of Engineering; it is a masters degree. where in the world is it recalled as an undergraduate degree?

Comment: For the sake of your doubts, 1: Yes, 2: No, [3-5]:n/a (not applicable as the questions themselves are invalid). I'm voting to close this question as a low quality post.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Hey meaning of it is right but recognition it is as a undergraduate degree.

Comment: Where is your source? Could you cite it?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Engineering#United_Kingdom

Comment: @ff524, could you assess the credibility of the statement that M.Eng. is an 'undergraduate' degree in the UK?

Comment: @ff524 wikipeadia says that undergraduate degree so other countries are assess that is as a undergraduate degree. I don't know there are assess that as a undergraduate degree in UK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30052/discussion-between-ebe-isaac-and-user38701).

Comment: A _Master's_ degree is almost always regraded as a graduate degree.  It's probably best to regard counter-examples as anomalous.

Comment: What's a **"_USA engineering courses membership_"**?  Do you mean the US's professional engineering certification ([PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_and_Practice_of_Engineering_Examination))?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience of the systems in the UK and Canada:

1. Yes, MSc is usually a 2-year research based postgraduate degree in North America.
2. No, MEng is also a 2-year postgraduate degree in North America. It is usually a taught masters degree - which means it is mainly based on coursework. In my experience a UK MEng is not usually considered a postgraduate degree as it is common for engineering programs to 'include' the MEng as part of the course ([University of Cambridge Undergraduate Engineering](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/undergraduates/undergraduates-overview))
3. Not exactly, while a UK MEng is often one additional year after the BEng making the time roughly equivalent to a Canada/US Bachelors degree. It is difficult to compare them as the systems are quite different (the difference becomes irrelevant after a few years of working in industry). A UK MEng would certainly not be equivalent to a 2-year research based MSc in North America (which doesn't really exist in the UK).
4. Are you sure you can be Chartered with a BEng? I believe you usually need a masters level qualification ([What do I need to do for Chartered Engineer (CEng) professional registration?](http://www.theiet.org/membership/profreg/ceng/requirements/index.cfm)). Although there are routes that don't require a Masters level qualification, that is the typical route. I assume by 'USA engineering courses membership' you mean in order to apply for an engineering license in the USA? In which case, this varies for each state. You would need to check the requirements for the state your are interested in (varies for each Provence in Canada also). In Canada I believe you would meet the academic requirements with the BEng ([PEng Academic Requirements - Ontario](http://peo.on.ca/index.php/ci_id/2058/la_id/1.htm))
5. Usually you need a 2-year research based masters degree (MSc) to apply for a PhD in North America. Although this could vary depending on the school.